# Parse JSON into dataframe but preserve id

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to analyze some response data (in a JSON blob) and join to other relevant records using an alphanumeric id. I am having trouble parsing the JSON while simultaneously keeping the id associated because my parsing method involves turning the JSON records into a list. Is there a good way of achieving this?

This data comes from a table that looks like:

responses                         | id
---|---
[{"description: Business type ... | 1bb15c61 
[{"description: Business type ... | 4bc12c99

Each record has one field that is the JSON block (a list containing multiple dictionaries) and an id.

The JSON looks something like this, but longer:

```
[{
    "description": "Business type",
    "input": "sole_proprietorship",
    "result": "approved
}, {
    "description": "Credit score",
    "input": 680,
    "result": "approved"
}]
```

I am reading it into a dataframe from a PSQL query. The JSON blob is called "responses". This is how I'm parsing it:

```py
parsed_list = []
for i, j in enumerate(df['responses']):
    try:
        parsed_list.append(json.loads(j))
    except:
        pass

parsed_df = []
for i, _ in enumerate(parsed_list):
    parsed_df.append(json_normalize(parsed_list[i]))

parsed_df = pd.concat(parsed_df)
```

This produces a usable dataframe from the JSON but obviously loses the id. One record yields multiple rows of data, and ideally I would want every row for a given record to be associated with the same id so that I can grab it later to join to other information.

description | input | result | id
---|---|---|--- 
Business type | sole_proprietorship | approved | 1bb15c61
Credit score | 680 | approved | 1bb15c61 Business type | non_profit | review | 4bc12c99 Credit score | 600 | approved | 4bc12c99

I think I need to be parsing the JSON differently, but I am not sure how to do so in a way that preserves the id.

Comment: It's totally unclear where you're drawing that ID from. Also, parsing JSON is not really that negotiable, the outcome is not variable, so your conclusion that you are parsing it wrongly is probably wrong.

Comment: The id is from the table that houses the JSON block. I don't think I am parsing it wrong, but I am looking for a method that allows me to keep the association with the id.

Comment: Can you update the data description to include the id field, to make it clear?

Comment: So, all that JSON talk is a red herring, because the ID is never included in the JSON. Instead, it is an ID that the DB associates with a row of a table. In that case, you need to keep track of it yourself after retrieving it from the DB. Suggestion: Define the data structure you want to have finally first, then try to get to it from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` function might solve your problem

```
df['responses'] = [{"description":"Business type", "input": "sole_proprietorship", "result": "approved"}, {"description": "Credit score","input": 680,"result": "approved"}]
df['id'] = [1bb15c61, 4bc12c99]

for i, j in zip(df['responses'], df['id']):
    print(i, j)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'description': 'Business type', 'input': 'sole_proprietorship', 'result': 'approved'} 1bb15c61
{'description': 'Credit score', 'input': 680, 'result': 'approved'} 4bc12c99
```

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I wanted, but I was having trouble parsing the id when it was just appended to the end. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
def try_parse_json(x):
    try:
        out = json.loads(x)
    except:
        out = "parsing error"
    return out

df_json = [try_parse_json(x) for x in parsed_df.responses]
flatten_df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_json, index=responses.id)
```

This gave me a wide dataframe with the id field next to its corresponding JSON that I could further manipulate into a usable state.